# Will there be a difference between Unity "Desktop" and Unity "Netbook" interface?

Tags: unity, ubuntu-netbook, 11.04

What has me slightly confused from all the different reports about Unity becoming the default shell in the 11.04 desktop edition:

Some claim and this is how most people seem to see it, that what currently is the UNE interface will be taken 1:1 (including any changes made during the Natty cycle) and used as the interface for the desktop version - meaning that the interface will be exactly the same for 11.04 UNE and UDE.

Some other reports talk more along the lines a "desktop unity", making it sound, that while both will be using Unity, the Desktop edition will get it's own Unity, tailored  specifically towards the Desktop formfactor. So both editions will be using Unity, but with slight differences in the layout or interface.

So my question is, will there be any difference between 11.04 Unity "Desktop" and Unity "Netbook" interface?

Comment: you should mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 16):

The details about this have been discussed at the Ubuntu Developer Summit. The blueprint with the information is [available here](https://blueprints.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-bringing-desktop-and-netbook-image-closer).

Comment: That's not the right blueprint I'm afraid. Unity will be the same code in desktop and netbook, but some configurable defaults will vary between the two, like whether or not applications are started maximised by default, and whether or not the Launcher is locked in view by default.

Answer (score 2):

For a short summary from [Unity’s Technical Lead Neil Patel interview with OMG!Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/exclusive-interview-with-unitys-technical-lead-neil-patel-this-is-a-must-read-folks/).

> Will Unity for Netbook Edition be any different to Unity for Desktop Edition come Natty?
>
> Yeah, all the things which we will change for the Desktop edition will automatically switch back to netbook-style when we detect a netbook. This will obviously need some good testing, and I’m leaning towards making it an option (autodetect / desktop / netbook) in case people want to use Desktop on netbook or vice versa.