# When will compiz-based version Unity be available for testing?

Tags: unity, compiz, 11.04

I've read in another question that Canonical has already ported Unity to Compiz, and that this new version has much better performance on supported hardware. Since the work is done, is there an expected date for Natty testers to get it?

Comment: I guess you can check it out of the bzr branch on Launchpad *now*...

Comment: Hmpf, so Canonical people are doing private branches?  Or this was just a quick PoC hack done by somebody?

Comment: Awesome. OMG! Ubuntu wrote post based on this question: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/compiz-based-unity-will-be-available-to-test-asap/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is available via the release of [Natty Alpha 1](http://www.ubuntu.com/testing/natty/alpha1).

There is currently a [PPA available](https://launchpad.net/~unity/+archive/ppa/+packages) that was made available for earlier releases of Natty, but this is now no longer necessary; The [Unity Installation Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/InstallationGuide) has intructions on how to install and test this.

Unfortunately due to complications with backporting parts of the GTK3 stack, Compiz, and Unity itself (and not breaking your existing desktop) there will **not** be a PPA for 10.10 (Maverick). Testing for Unity will have to be done on Natty itself. More information on this development is available on Didier Roche's [status report mail](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2010-November/032078.html) to the ubuntu-devel mailing list.

The source code is [available here](https://code.launchpad.net/unity):  or with the following command `bzr branch lp:unity`

Comment: I don't find any problems in OMGUbuntu reporting it. They even quoted the source to make it sure that it wasn't a random "I heard from some personal contacts". It is good that people might know that might be available soon. In  any case Ryan Paul and Jorge Castro are the two people who are giving out most information, so this info means something

Answer (score 2):

We don't know for sure yet, but once all the developers are home from UDS (the Ubuntu Developer Summit) I'm sure more information will slowly trickle out.

I'd say it's very much possible we'll have runnable examples within the next few weeks. Having said that Canonical may want to polish things a bit more, so people don't immediately jump to conclusions about an unfinished version of Desktop Unity.

I'd be surprised if we get to Christmas and there's no sign of it though... it's a rather major new thing to be tested!

Comment: Oh, I thought the compiz-based version would be released first, then at some point the desktop version would. Considering that (AFAIK) the compiz version is done and the desktop version is being projected.

Comment: We don't know yet [how separate the Desktop and Netbook versions are](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9900/will-there-be-a-difference-between-11-04-unity-desktop-and-unity-netbook-inte) going to be. I'd be very surprised if Canonical made no major improvements to the Netbook version in the next six months...

Answer (score 0):

Tomorrow apparently.12th November

Just read this over on OMG Ubuntu (credit them)

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/compiz-based-unity-coming-to-ppa-tomorrow/