# Will Unity be in the Natty Alpha 1?

Tags: unity, 11.04

I would like to try Unity in desktop version. Will it be available in the Alpha 1 release?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is [planned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9941/when-will-compiz-based-version-unity-be-available-for-testing/10001#10001) to get Compiz 0.9.4 and Unity work together for Alpha 1 (which is a month away), so I'm pretty sure we will be able to test Unity at least via a PPA by then.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the unity right now in 10.04 or 10.10.

run this in your terminal:

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-netbook

or

sudo apt-get install unity

after logging out you will be able to choose Ubuntu Netbook Edition

Comment: I tried this but it tell me that i haven't got the right drivers

Comment: 10.04 doesn't have unity?!

Comment: only the netbook version