# Unity testing process

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will compiz-based version Unity be available for testing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9941/when-will-compiz-based-version-unity-be-available-for-testing)

Im really excited about Unity. I know youre getting alot of hate atm, but there are alot of support out there aswell :)

Im wondering how the testing process for the Unity that will be default in Natty will work. I know i can install the current Unity version in Maverick, but id like to test the new one based on Compiz. So will this be open to testing for everyone and when do you see something like that happening?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but close enough; when it actually is ready there will be a test methodology announced, etc. etc.

Comment: The current unity does not get on well with my nvidia driver so I would love to be able to try out the compiz based unity, It worries me that this unproven desktop is going live so soon, But if it works it will be very exciting.