# How to use Compiz as the window manager for Unity

Tags: 10.10, unity, compiz, mutter

When I tried to enable compiz, it said that I can't because of mutter. How may I enable compiz?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use compiz for the current Unity version, the compiz integrated version will be available in 11.04 (Currently in development).

Comment: Might be a good idea to add that it's for Natty Alpha 1 + only...

Answer (score 2):

You can not currently use Compiz with Unity. However a Compiz version of Unity is in the works. More info on that here: [When will compiz-based version Unity be available for testing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9941/when-will-compiz-based-version-unity-be-available-for-testing/10001#10001)

Comment: It's for Natty Alpha 1 + only...