# How to use compiz with Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition?

Tags: unity, compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use Compiz as the window manager for Unity.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11399/how-to-use-compiz-as-the-window-manager-for-unity)

Hello. I am using Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition with classic desktop interface (No Unity). For visual and usability purposes, I want to use compiz. I, however, afraid Unity support will be broken when i install on my machine.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the standard GNOME ("Ubuntu Desktop Edition") session, it should already default to Compiz if it works on your hardware. You don't have to separately install it.

You should be able to switch to Unity by choosing the "Ubuntu Netbook Edition" session without problems, in which case Compiz won't be running, and won't interfere with Unity in any way.