# Does Compiz Work on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, compiz

I am runing Ubuntu 11.10 and was wondering if compiz (I think that is the right name for the program, the one that lets you have wobbly windows right?) works on Ubuntu 11.10. I saw some comments in software that didn't look so hopefull like that it will crash the system... Is this true? Is there a way to make it not crash?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Ubuntu 11.10 uses unity which is a plug in of Compiz, but still playing with Compiz is dangerous in Ubuntu 11.10.

[image]

Linked Questions

1. [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)
2. [When will compiz-based version Unity be available for testing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9941/when-will-compiz-based-version-unity-be-available-for-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it works. And in some rare cases it may crash the system. In such cases, resetting to default values will fix the issue

Open a Terminal or Press Alt+F2 and type

```
unity --reset
```

If you want to reset icons as well

```
unity --reset-icons
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiz works and is in fact an integral part of Unity 3D as stated by "I'm not this person". I've played with all the different desktop environments and ultimately decided to piece together my own.

- Unity-2D panel, but without the Unity launcher
- Avant Window Navigator as my launcher and window manager + Cardapio
  as my start menu
- Compiz instead of Metacity as the windows manager, adds functionality
  and effects.

[image]

If Ubuntu can increase the performance of Unity I'll switch but until then it's not usable for me.